# Populate Form Based on dropdown value in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have about 30 different forms that will be displayed in a wizard, a form will be displayed based on the value from the dropdown selected, if all forms are created in a view file it doesn't seem effective, I try to save each form in the database and it will Called based on the dropdown value but not as expected, please help with this problem.
this is the code example that I saved into the database:

```
<label>Yang Bertandatangan Dibawah ini:</label>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Nama</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <select name="pemberi" class="form-control select-search" required data-fouc>
                        <option value="">--pilih--</option>
                        <?php
                          if(is_array($pegawai)){
                            foreach($pegawai as $row){
                            ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $row->nip;?>"><?php echo $row->nama;?></option>
                            <?php
                            }
                          }
                         ?>
                      </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                  <label>MEMERINTAHKAN:</label>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Kepada:</label>
                                </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Nama:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <select name="penerima" class="form-control select-search" required data-fouc>
                        <option value="">--pilih--</option>
                        <?php
                          if(is_array($pegawai)){
                            foreach($pegawai as $row){
                            ?>
                              <option value="<?=$row->nip;?>"><?=$row->nama;?></option>
                            <?php
                            }
                          }
                         ?>
                      </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">Jabatan:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                      <select name="jabatan_penerima" class="form-control select-search" required data-fouc>
                        <option value="">--pilih--</option>
                        <?php
                          if(is_array($pembuat)){
                            foreach($pembuat as $row){
                            ?>
                              <option value="<?=$row->id;?>"><?=$row->nama_jabatan;?></option>
                            <?php
                            }
                          }
                         ?>
                      </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                <label>Untuk:</label>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Isi Perintah" name="isisurat" id="isisurat" required></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

The code runs well if it is directly written in source code, but different if called from the database

[as expected if I write the code in page directly:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn2j6.png)

[If I save the code in database and call based on value of dropdown,it will show error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNqVg.png)

Comment: I'll be able to help you better if you provide us with some code and show us what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use normal load views based on a condition like in your index you would do this:

```
<a href="<?= site_url('your_controller/your_method/your_desired_view_one'); ?>">VIEW ONE</a>
<a href="<?= site_url('your_controller/your_method/your_desired_view_two'); ?>">VIEW TWO</a>
// and so on ...
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function your_method($your_view)
{
    $data['view'] = $this->load->view($your_view, null, TRUE);
    // Setting third param as true will return the view as a string
    $this->load->view('main_view', $data);
}
```

Now in your main view you have a variable called view of your requested view just echo it in your main content area.